# Does if (myBool == true) differ computational wise to if(myBool)?

Tags: optimization, if-statement, compiler-construction, coding-style

I read a coding style suggestion about comparing bools that said to write

```
if (myBoolValue == true) { ... }
if (myBoolValue == false) { ... }
```

instead of writing

```
if (myBoolValue) { ... }
if (!myBoolValue) { ... }
```

since it **increases readability** of the code even though they are **equivalent statements**. I am well aware that it is not a usual coding practice but I will agree that it may increase readability in some cases.

My question is if there is any difference between the two in regards of optimization of code execution or if (a well implemented) compiler translate them to the same thing?

Comment: Very dubious recommendation. Many people, certainly including me, consider that redundant syntax *reduces* readability.

Comment: I also think it reduces readability. Shouldn't make a difference to compiled code, though.

Comment: FYI https://maurus.net/resources/programming-languages/php/ "`(string)"false" == (int)0` is *true*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The productions are not the same in all languages.

For instance, they may produce different results for some "non-boolean" values of "myBoolValue" in both JavaScript and C.

```
// JavaScript
[] == true         // false
[] ? true : false  // true

// C
#define true 1
#define false 0
int x = -1;
x == true         // 0 (false)
x ? true : false  // true (1)
```

To see what a *specific* compiler does for a *specific* programming language (there is both what it is allowed to do and then what it will do), check the generated assembly/machine/byte code.

(Anyway, *I* prefer and use the latter form exclusively.)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from cases like JavaScript and I guess Java with autoboxing and Boolean, where the semantics can differ between the two forms, it really depends on compiler optimization.

I never understand this recommendation. If `myBool` is a boolean, so is `(myBool == true),` so why doesn't it require `((myBool == true) == true)`, and so on forever? Where does this stop? Surely the answer is not to start in the first place?

Surely the more there is to read, the less readable it is?

Comment: `((myBool == true) == true)` **increases readability** ..! xD

Answer (score 0):

In C (and many other languages) there's no boolean type, all are numeric expression, so `myBoolValue` may be equal to 2 or any value different from 0 and 1, and comparing them numerically won't give you the correct result.

```
#define true 1
#define false 0
if (5 == true) //...
```

To improve readability, name the variable meaningful (such as isNonZero, isInGoodState, isClosed, LoopEnded...) rather than comparing them with `true`

Another way is comparing them with 0 or false when you need the true case (`myBoolValue != false`). Also, using bool type (if it's available) may solve some problems.

Comment: As of the 1999 standard, C does have a built-in boolean type called `_Bool` (and aliased as `bool` if you have `#include <stdio.h>`).

Answer (score 0):

The behavior depends on the language and on the type of the value being tested. The two forms are *not* equivalent in all cases.

In C, conditions are commonly represented using integers, with `0` being treated as false and any non-zero value being treated as true. Comparing such a value for equality to `true` is invalid; for example, if the value happens to be 2 or -1, it's logically true but not equal to `true`. As of C99, C does have a built-in boolean type called `_Bool`, aliased as `bool` if you have `#include <stdbool.h>`. But it's still common to use other types, particularly `int` to represent conditions, and even to redefine `bool`, `false`, and `true` in various ways.

C++ has has a built-in `bool` type, with `false` and `true` literals, since very early in its development, but it still retains much of its C ancestry. Other C-inspired languages are likely to have similar issues.

In languages that have a built-in boolean type *and don't allow values of other types to be used directly as conditions*, `if (x)` and `if (x == true)` are more likely to be equivalent. And if they're semantically equivalent, I would expect any decent optimizing compiler to generate the same code for either form, or very nearly so.

But I strongly disagree with the style advice. An explicit comparison to `false` or `true`, even in cases where it's equivalent to testing the value directly, do not IMHO aid readability.

If you have a variable whose value denotes a condition, it's more important to give it a name that indicates that. Programming language code shouldn't necessarily follow English grammar, but something like

```
if (file_is_open)
```

is not made more readable by changing it to

```
if (file_is_open == true)
```

As a C programmer, I like to write my conditions more explicitly than a lot of other programmers do; I'll write `if (ptr != NULL)` rather than `if (ptr)`, and `if (c != '\0')` rather than `if (c)`. But if a variable is already a condition, I see no point in adding a superfluous comparison.

And `value == true` is itself a condition; if `if (value == true)` is supposed to be more readable than `if (value)`, why wouldn't `if ((value == true) == true)` be even better?